# Trying to understand why meta compatibility tag resolved jQuery error

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I'm looking for an explanation as to why a particular fix worked so I can better understand the mechanics of what's going on.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application; "everything was working just fine" (TM) until I allowed NuGet to update the jQuery package(s).

Then, when I tried to run the webapp in IE 10, I started getting error messages / exceptions to the tune of:

```
Unhandled exception at line 3398, column 4 in http://localhost:53242/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Unhandled exception at line 7, column 38 in http://localhost:53242/Scripts/bootstrap.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

I was unable to recreate with Firefox and Chrome.  Neither Firefox 27 nor Chrome 31 threw those errors when I opened the page in those browsers.

This is the relevant section of jquery-2.1.0.js

```
jQuery.ready.promise = function( obj ) {
    if ( !readyList ) {
        
        readyList = jQuery.Deferred();
            
        // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the browser event has already occurred.
        // we once tried to use readyState "interactive" here, but it caused issues like the one
        // discovered by ChrisS here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282#comment:15
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
            setTimeout( jQuery.ready );
            
        } else {
            
            // Use the handy event callback
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );  //This is line 3398
            
            // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
            window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false );
        }
    }
    return readyList.promise( obj );
};
```

The fix that I found was to add this line

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
```

to the `<head>` of my `_LayoutBootstrap.cshtml` file.

#### My Question:

Why does adding that `meta` tag to the `head` of the document resolve the errors that I was seeing?

The explanation given was that the tag "forces IE to use the best mode that it can".  Assuming that's correct, what does that mean and why wasn't IE able to figure out the correct behavior without that tag?

---

Issue described in [full detail here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1964604.aspx?Error+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+Express+2013+Web) along with another person having the same issue in an unsupported IE 8.  If you're curious, recreate steps are included approximately 2/3rds of the way into the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It resolves your problem because by adding the compatibility flag, you're forcing the browser into the latest version rather than allowing it to choose compatibility mode (which is IE7 mode, which isn't supported by jquery 2.x)

IE defaults to compatibility mode depending on the settings you have set within the browser. For example, by default, intranet sites (local network sites) will automatically open in compatibility mode.

You should be using conditional comments to include the 1.1x version of jquery when an older version of IE is being used (IE<10) which will completely avoid this issue, allowing your users to use whatever browser they want without having to modify their settings to properly use your application.

Comment: It kind of boggles my mind that I actually have to tell IE "go ahead, show me what you can actually do."  But I have done enough enterprise sysAd work to understand why that's the case.  Thanks for the suggestion on conditional logic regarding which version of jQuery to use.